# Can a variable act as a space in VBS?

Tags: vbscript, character, space

I'm teaching myself VBS and I decided to write a message encryption program.  It uses the left and right functions in a loop to read every individual character.

```
DO 
wscript.sleep 100
if Az=0 then
EXIT DO
end if
CR=right(message,aZ)
DEL=left(CR,1)
aZ=aZ-1
zZ=zZ+1
supra=""
supra="supra"
CALL KEYCOUNT
CD=left(keyword,zZ)
TAC=right(CD,1)
....
```

From there, it sets every character equal to a different letter based on an encryption keyword and moves onto the next character.  My problem is I don't know how to deal with spaces in the message.  Is there a way to make a variable have the value of a space?  I've tried:

```
set var=space(1)
set var="&"" ""&"
set var=""
set var=" "
set var=""" """
```

I'm certain there are things I'm not thinking of

Thanks

Joseph

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_space.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set` statement assigns an object reference to a variable or property, or associates a procedure reference with an event. That isn't our case.

```
var=space(1)  ' var contains one space character
var="&"" ""&" ' var contains &" "&
var=""        ' var contains a string of zero length
var=" "       ' var contains one space character
var=""" """   ' var contains " "
```

Or, if you would like, declare a constant for use in place of literal value of space (anywhere in your script) as follows:

```
Const vbSp=" "
```

Constants are public by default. Within procedures, constants are always private; their visibility can't be changed. Within a script, the default visibility of a script-level constant can be changed using the `Private` keyword. There are variations:

```
Private Const vbSp=" "
Public  Const vbSp=" "
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `Set` (cf. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)) when assigning a simple/non-object value to a variable. If you loose it, your experimental statements will 'work' (compile & run without error). Look at the output and you'll see that

```
var = " "
```

is the correct and most efficient way to assign a (string containing one) space to a variable.